# Find equation based on known x and answers

Tags: algorithm, math, linear-algebra

So basically I have something like this

```
[always 8 numbers]
5-->10
2-->4
9-->18
7-->14
```

I know four x and the answers for that four x. I need to find equation so it fits for all of those x and their answers. I know there is infinite number of equations possible, but I would like to solve for shortest ones if possible.

For this example
x*2 or x+x fits the best
of course something like this x*3-x and infinite number of other equations works also but they're not most optimal ones like x*2

Any ideas, theories or algorithms that solve similar problem?

Comment: `x*2`, `x*3-x`, and `x+x` are of course all equivalent.  But there are other answers that would not be equivalent: `2*x+(x-2)*(x-5)*(x-9)*(x-7)` for example.  Do you know that your answer will always be a polynomial of degree at most 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the numbers you provided:

```
5-->10
2-->4
9-->18
7-->14
```

You want to find a, b, c and d that solve the system defined by:

```
ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = f(x)
```

So, in your case it is:

```
125a + 25b + 5c + d = 10
8a + 4b + 2c + d = 4
729a + 81b + 9c + d = 18
343a + 49b + 7c + d = 14
```

If you solve the system you'll find that (a,b,c,d) must be (0, 0, 2, 0). So, the minimum polynomial is 2x.

I made a website some time ago that solves this:

http://juanlopes.net/actually42/#5%2010%202%204%209%2018%207%2014/true/true

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to fit the data to a polynomial function, i.e. something like:

f(x) = a_0 + a_1*x + a_2*x^2 + ... + a_n*x^n where each a_i is a real (or complex) number,

then there is some theory available as to when it is possible to put all those points on a single curve.  What you can do is pick a degree (the highest power of x) and then write down a system of equations and solve the system (or try to solve it).  For example, if the degree is 2, then your data become:

10 = a_0 + a_1*5 + a_2*5^2

4 = a_0 + a_1*2 + a_2*2^2

etc

If you are able to solve the system, then great.  If not, you need a larger degree.  Solving the system can be done (built in) in many languages via matrix multiplication.  You may want to start out by saying: can my data all fit on a polynomial of degree 1? if yes, done.  If not, does it fit on degree 2 polynomial? if yes, done.  If not, degree 3, etc.  Be careful though, because in general you may have data that you cannot fit "exactly" to a polynomial (or any function for that matter).  If you just want a low degree polynomial that is very close, then you want to look into polynomial regression (which will give you a best fit polynomial), see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression